# ptrace system call returns -1 with errno=0

Tags: c, system-calls

I am trying to do some very basic stuff using ptrace but I am a getting a really odd behavior.

```
unsigned long start=strtoul(start_text,NULL,16);

long start_data; 
 if ((start_data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT,child_pid,(void*)start,NULL))<0){
      free_memory(vars,registers,size);
      exit(1);
}
```

`start_text` is a string to a valid place in another program, the value of `start` is correct, the value of `child_pid` is also correct.

For some reason, for some values of `start` the call works properly, but for some it fails.

I tried to understand what causes this so I wrote this:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT,child_pid,(void*)start,NULL);
printf("%d",errno);
```

but `errno` is 0 every time.

Can anyone please explain what causes the problem?

Comment: ptrace will always set errno on an error -- but `PTRACE_PEEKTEXT` may return a negative value (if the value read is negative) without an error.  To detect errors with PEEKTEXT, you need to set `errno = 0` before the ptrace call and check it afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Linux's `ptrace` man page:

> Since the value returned by
> a  successful PTRACE_PEEK* request may be -1, the caller must clear errno before the call, and
> then check it afterward to determine whether or not an error occurred.

That is, it could be that the value you're reading just happens to be `-1`, or in your case, some other negative number (i.e. a 64-bit value with the high bit set).

So unlike most other system call functions, you can't check for success by testing whether the returned value is negative.  You should instead do

```
errno = 0;
start_data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT,child_pid,(void*)start,NULL));
if (errno != 0) {
    // handle error
}
```

Note the importance of setting `errno = 0` first.  As with other system calls, if `ptrace` succeeds it may leave the value of `errno` **unchanged**.   So unless you clear `errno` first, you won't be able to tell whether a nonzero value afterward indicates that `ptrace` failed, or whether `ptrace` succeeded and the value was left over from some previous call that failed.

(My version of  man page suggests that the `ptrace` library wrapper may actually set `errno` to zero upon success, but doesn't make it clear exactly when, so it is best not to rely on this behavior.)

Comment: Nitpick: the system calls themselves have no concept of `errno`, and the `ptrace` system call reports errors like any other. This question is purely a consequence of the libc wrappers.